# Biopython initial installation tests fail

Tags: python, windows, installation, biopython

I am trying to ensure biopython has installed successfully on my windows machine. In windows powershell I call `pip install biopython`. Afterward I get a successfully installed message. The [installation guide](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/tree/master#biopython-readme-file) recommends running tests to ensure proper installation. I try running these in the "source code directory" (shown below) per the instructions and always get an error message:

```
C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\biopython-1.81.dist-info
```

the commands are:

```
pip install -e .
python setup.py test
```

It is worth noting that there is no script by that name in the named folder and so I'm unsure of why they'd be recommending running such a script.

tried what I was instructed (command named above), get following error message:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -iopython (c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
Obtaining file:///C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages/biopython-1.81.dist-info
ERROR: file:///C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages/biopython-1.81.dist-info does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The [`documentation`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/tree/master#installation-from-source) mentions that testing `BioPython` is ***only*** for when you **install it from source**. What you did was **install it with pip**. Which installs the pre-compiled binary wheels available on `PyPI`. These pre-compiled binary wheels should have been tested by the developers before uploading them to `PyPI`.